# Java Properties File: Useful Case of Empty Property Value?

Tags: java, properties

I am messing with properties-files in Java. I want to know if there are some properties-files that use empty values ('propertyName=\n') and what they are used for?

[Update]

Since some folks are still irritated here is a better description:

A sample properties file might look like:

```
database.username = john
database.password = johnsSecret
```

Ok so its simple. Now the question is if someone have seen something like:

```
anyProperty =
```

I am just asking if you know a use case that actually happen where you needed to express an empty property value within a property file and why was it.

PS: This is no social experiment, it is to determine if this case is practical needed or if I can use it to express the desire to remove the property when specifying a delta to transform an existing properties file by adding or removing its entries. Alternatively I will use `-propertyname` to remove any property.

Comment: It may be useful for unsetting some default values.

Comment: That is exactly the thing I try to use by removing them entirely. If it has empty value it is gone. But if there are valid use cases I am not aware of I would like to know them up front.

Comment: I can't come up with any other use case but unsetting an already set value or excplicitely stating that some property is not set.

Comment: Thanks. That something is not know in the wild is a very important information :-). Usually overshadowing properties by another properties file is quite uncommon and it seams that it is even can be considered evil. Think about a path '/foo' being unset by overshadowing it with ''. It requires additional logic for an application to understand that '' means actually nothing. That's why I think that merging properties actually should remove the key and say its not there. So I ask this (hard) question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is so vague I vote to close for "unclear what you are asking", it's so strange that even seems to be a social experiment to analyse people answers from random generated questions..

Having said that, this code saves and read a properties files with what you are asking for.

```
//Write
String fileName="fileInTheWild.properties";
Properties prop= new Properties(); 
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileName );
prop.put("propertyName", "\n");
prop.store(fos, "Some Properties"); 

//Read
prop.load(new FileReader(fileName));    
String newLine= prop.getProperty("propertyName");
System.out.println("Line 1" + newLine +"Line 2");
```

Comment: What is so vague on the question? I do not get you folks... .

Comment: @MartinKersten Now after your edit, it's less vague, so are you asking for how to differentiate a null property from an empty property? you could explicitly use anyProperty = null, or if the question is when do you actually use empty properties? Then any optional property meets that criteria, even inside the program you can threat it as an empty value or as a null, as your choice, for an optional middle name field I would prefer an empty space rather than a wrong null..

Comment: Actually I want to know if this is used in the wild. I mean a middle name of "" would be wrong I guess since you either have a (populated) middle name or none and none is expressed by =null (or Optional.empty which is mapped to null content).  So if you know an API that forces you to use "" instead I would like to know. What I write is for inhouse use but I want to prevent maintenance costs downstream so I try to get this fact right but if one runs into this he has to understand change bla bla... costs money... .